# Не запускается php-скрипт на Denwer

Tags: php, html

Ввожу в адресную строку: 
 http://localhost/cloudrap/index.php

Выводит следующее:

The requested URL /cloudrap/index.php was not found on this server.
**Подсказка Денвера** 
Вы ошиблись при наборе URL в браузере. Вероятнее всего, сервер пытается найти файл Z:/home/localhost/www/cloudrap/, которого не существует. 
В случае использования CGI-скриптов, корректные пути к CGI-директориям следующие: 
**URL   Куда указывает**

http://***/cgi-glob/script.cgi   /home/cgi-glob/script.cgi
http://***/cgi/script.cgi        /home/***/cgi/script.cgi
http://***/cgi-bin/script.cgi    /home/***/cgi-bin/script.cgi
Путь скрипта index.php: 
Z:\home\cloudrap\index.php

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: логи сервера в студию

Answer (score 1):

В адресную строку нужно просто ввести http://cloudrap

Answer (score 0):

Путь: `Z:\home\cloudrap\www\index.php`

Адрес: `http://cloudrap/index.php`

Или

Путь: `Z:/home/localhost/www/cloudrap/index.php`

Адрес: `http://localhost/cloudrap/index.php`

[Подробнее](http://www.denwer.ru/base.html) - раздел "Работа с виртуальными хостами"

Все виртуальные хосты, после запуска Денвера, прописаны в файле `hosts` (Win 7 - C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc). Можете запустить и посмотреть прописался ли ваш хост, если нет, смотрите логи и ошибки для начала.

Comment: Ничего не работает. Я это уже пробовал много раз

Comment: Вы уверены что у вас вообще сервер стартует?

Comment: Да, стартует. Проверил

Comment: Ну диск смонтировался, это не значит что все остальное работает. Вообще давно с Денвером не работал не помню что там к чему.

Comment: http://localhost/denwer/ - открывается?

Comment: Да. С этим нет проблем

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45521/discussion-between-bookin-and-user207012).

Answer (score -3):

Проверь название файла index.php если ты его переименовывал из текстового файла возможно он сохранился как index.php.txt 
Что-бы проверить набери http://cloudrap/ и если денвер не найдет файл index.php или index.html в браузер выведется список файлов в корне сайта если там index.php.txt  то надо его переименовать.

Внимательно проверь что-бы файл был в этой директории Z:\home\cloudrap\www\index.php
и перезагрузить сервер и зайти по адресу
 http://cloudrap/index.php

Comment: Перезагружал Denwer - не работает.

Comment: проверь что находится в файле Z:\usr\local\apache\conf\vhosts.conf